# Why i cant get the array length base on my ajax function result

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, variables

i have a problem about this, i want to get the array length of my array data so that i can use it in my loop. Why i am not getting it by using this code : `var arrayLength = myclinicsID.length;` , i declared myclinicsID in a global variable and i also push data with other function and then now, i want to get the length of that array so that i can use it with my loop, now here is my full code:

```
function getbarxAxis() {
  getallclinics();
  var arrayLength = myclinicsID.length;
 $.ajax({
   url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardata_date",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(data) {
     for (var i in myclinicsID) {
       categories.push(data[i]["datemonths"]);

          for(var innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < arrayLength; i++) {
            //getbarSeriesData(myclinicsID[innerLoop],data[i]['datemonths']);
          }
     }
   }
 });
}
```

here is my `getallclinics();` full code where i populate the myclinicsID array:

```
function getallclinics() {
   $.ajax ({
          url: siteurl+"patients_report/seriesclinics",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data) {
            for(var i in data) {
              myclinicsNAME.push(data[i]['clinic_name']);
              myclinicsID.push(data[i]['clinic_id']);
            }
          }
   });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your AJAX call succeeds?

Comment: hmm how can i make sure of it? @GopsAB please help me

Comment: Add a Error call back and have a break point if u r using IDE or else use console.log.

Comment: Try to see `data` in console inside `success`.

Comment: POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/seriesclinics
@Mamun

Comment: how can i do that @GopsAB sorry sir, just a beginner

Comment: Most probably it tries to get `myclinicsID.length` not waiting for `ajax` response of `getallclinics()`

Comment: @kzharas210 yes sir, i think that is what happened, how can i avoid it ?

Comment: @kzharas210 how can i be sure that my first function was finished before running my ajax ?

Comment: @JcJohn You need a synchronous `ajax` execution by specifying `async: false`.

Comment: @kzharas210 . can you give me some example so that i can follow with that? . a very simple to understand please. i am just a beginner

Comment: @JcJohn try `dataType: "JSON", async: false, success: function(data) {`

Comment: @kzharas210 in what function would i put that? at first or at second?

Comment: @JcJohn inside `getallclinics()`

Comment: @kzharas210 so, you mean, i will only add async: false?

Comment: @JcJohn yes, only that

Comment: @kzharas210 thanks, can you explain me why? and whats wrong if i didn't add async: false? . i need to know what was happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142565/discussion-between-jc-john-and-kzharas210).

Comment: @kzharas210 can you explain to me when to use async: false or why ? or whats with in it?